# What project template to use for an 8bit RPG?

Tags: unity, rpg

Should I use a 2D or 3D dimension for an 8-bit RPG game in Unity? I have been searching and I haven't found anything on this yet. Can anyone please tell me the better option because sometimes people recommend to do 3D just in case, but I don't want to mess anything up later on.

Comment: Is 8-bit 3D even a thing?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain properly i mean when i am creating a unity project should I pick the 3D preset or 2D.

Comment: How would that 8bit rpg look like? What kind of graphics you have or planning to make.

Comment: I am planning to have pixelated graphics

Comment: The Unity Manual has an article about this question: [2D or 3D project](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/2Dor3D.html).

Comment: @FluffytheTogekiss There are some modern top-down perspective games which have a nostalgic pixel-art aesthetic but are actually full-fledged 3d environments under the hood. It makes a few things easier, like maps with multiple walkable layers and lighting. But that's not something I would recommend to a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter that much what project template you use, because it actually changes very little. Anything it changes [can be changed back after you created the project](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/2DAnd3DModeSettings.html).

And it does not lock you out of any features either. You will have both the 2d and the 3d features of the engine available, no matter if you choose 2d or 3d when you create your project. You can in fact mix and match sprites and meshes in the same scene without issues. The only part of the engine where 2d and 3d are separated are the physics engines. 2D colliders won't interact with regular (3D) colliders. But they can still coexist in the same scene.

For more information on this topic check out the article [2D or 3D projects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/2Dor3D.html) from the Unity Manual.

That being said, for a game where environment and characters are represented by sprites and not by 3d models, you likely want to start with the **2d template**, because then any image files you import will by default be imported as sprites and not as textures. You can change the import type of an image asset very easily, but it's still more convenient to have the right preset.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your game to be 2D, choose 2D, if you want it to be 3D, choose 3D.